# enum field not being properly retrieved ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enums

I'm having some issues using ActiveRecord's enums in a Rails application.

**Context**: The enum field represents the `status` of an object, for the sake of simplicity, I've included the piece of code that matters for this problem:

```rb
class Issue < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: %i[open in_progress closed rejected]
  has_many_attached :files
  belongs_to :issuer, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :issuer_id

  validates_presence_of :title, :description, :issuer, :issued_at, :updated_at

  after_initialize do |issue|
    issue.issued_at = DateTime.now
    issue.updated_at = issue.issued_at
    issue.status = :open
  end

  after_update do |issue|
    issue.updated_at = DateTime.now
  end
end
```

I'm writing some specs and I've noticed that everytime I try to fetch the model using ActiveRecord's API (e.g. `Model.all`), every record comes with the first status (`open`). When I query the database, the tables related to this model contains the statuses that I've set for the objects I've stored in the database.

It seems that ActiveRecord is having some trouble when mapping from table to model, but not vice versa. Any ideas of what can be causing this behavior?

I'm using PostgreSQL as database and Rails 5.2.2

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have added `issue.status = :open` in after_initialize block. this will be called every time you initialize an object. weather its `Model.create` or `Model.new` or `Model.find` or `Model.all` Every time after initializing that object its overwriting its status to :open. User after initialize in models is not a good idea. For many such chased where I want to initialize any new object I set default for column or before_validation callback.